# font size looks different in safari and google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

during development I encountered the problem that my page in Safari and in Google Chrome is displayed differently. namely, I’m talking about the font size, if I specify the font size as 2in, in Safari it looks very small, but in Google Chrome everything looks as it should be, what is the problem and how can it be solved?

how page looks in safari
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63uX2.jpg)

how page looks in google chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poibt.jpg)

Thought that problem is different screen width, but even i I stretch it in developer mode it doesnt works well

Comment: What unit is `fw` supposed to be? At least https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length doesn't appear to mention any such thing.

Comment: Do you mean vw?

Comment: I mean 2 vw guys, not 2 in

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet so we can easily try this for ourselves. Also what systems are you using (OS and devices)? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example